# Switching new dimmer for old dimmer

Tags: electrical

My new dimmer for LED lighting has four wires: one black, one red, one red/white and a green ground. The old dimmer only has three wires: a single red, single black and green ground. This is also going to be a three way. How do I install?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I edited your post for clarity; please sure I did it right. Did your dimmer come with installation instructions? And how is this to work with a three-way switch?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box you're installing the dimmer into?

Comment: what do you mean "going to be" a 3-way?  Are you also adding a second switch?   Is this on a stairway or other place 3-ways are mandatory?

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain unanswered and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dimmer is similar to [the Lutron dimmer in this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148749/can-i-replace-this-dimmer/148753#148753):

The new dimmer can be used as a regular switch or a 3-way switch.

#### For a regular switch, which it sounds like the way your old dimmer was connected:

- Black - Hot
- Red - Switched Hot
- Green - Ground
- Red/White - *Not used - cap with a wire nut*

#### For a 3-way switch:

- Black - Hot
- Red - Switched Hot/Traveler 1
- Red/White - Switched Hot/Traveler 2
- Green - Ground

The second switch for a 3-way setup should be a **regular switch**, not another dimmer.

Wiring a 3-way switch can be a bit confusing. Search for other information on that (plenty on DIY StackExchange, or Google it) and then just treat the dimmer as one of the 3-way switches.